# The best practice to search on solr with wildcard at the beginning and at the end

Tags: solr

I want to search text within words, as *foo* to find barfoobar or foobar or barfoo With solr.

My field type configuration is:

```
<fieldtype name="searchableContentTokenized" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="char-mapping.txt" />
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s\&quot;]+" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="char-mapping.txt" />
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s\&quot;]+" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

When use *foo* in query (q=content:* foo *) the search takes too long because my index the has 500,000 documents and occupies 30 GB.

There is a better way to do the search?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: For one of my Solr Collection that handles more than 2 millions documents I use field type `text_ar` - it is Arabic contents - In the example schema you should find such field type for English, uncomment if necessary and change your field to it or to the language of content..

Answer (score 1):

try with the below field type

```
<fieldType name="text_reference" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50" side="front"/>
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50" side="back"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```